# Analog feedback control

Tags: control

Is there a simple way to implement closed loop control with analog electronics and not programmable controllers? Does off the shelf equipment exist to do this?

For example, if a 0-10V analog control signal to some device was 5V (50% output) and a transducer feeding back a measurement of the process variable was not showing 50% output, the electronics would adjust the analog input signal to reduce the error, with a proportional gain or something.

The feedback is from a physical measurement e.g. temperature.

Do effective methods exists to do this or is it a flawed idea?

Comment: This is what control *was* for decades.

Comment: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/an05f.pdf

Comment: Note that the resistor RE which stabilizes each common emitter gain stage does nothing else than to provide negative feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it can be done with analog electronics. The field of control systems existed long before digital computers were put in the loop. It sounds like you just need an operational amplifier.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f15aXd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. An operational amplifier used to control a transistor amplifier as a current source.*

> For example, if a 0-10V analog control signal to some device was 5V (50% output) and a transducer feeding back a measurement of the process variable was not showing 50% output, the electronics would adjust the analog input signal to reduce the error, with a proportional gain or something.

- In Figure 1 R1 provides the 0 - 10 V signal. This is used to drive a 0 to 10 V output at Node4 using an NPN transistor, Q1.
- Q1 has some non-linearities and a voltage offset so we need to correct these.
- The negative feedback from Node4 to the inverting input of OA1 provides the correction. The op-amp's high gain amplifies any minor differences between the two inputs and, in this configuration, moves in such a way to minimise the difference between its two inputs.
- The result is that V<sub>NODE4</sub> = V<sub>R1</sub>.

> Is there a simple way to implement closed loop control with analog electronics and not programmable controllers?

Yes.

> Does off the shelf equipment exist to do this?

Yes. Audio amplifiers, servo motors (RC aircraft, CD/DVD players, etc.), camera focus control, cruise control, and thousands of other systems use this technique.